# Swift: Export strings to CSV with cell line breaks

Tags: swift, string, csv, export-to-csv

I need to export some strings in CSV. All work fine, but I can't set up a line break in a cell. `\t`, `\n`, `\r` is not suitable because it simply wraps text on a new line.

```
func export() {

    let fileName = "Test.csv"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    var csvText = "Date,1,2,3\n"

    if history.count != 0 {

        var all = ""
        let date = "24.08.2019"
        let x1 = "[10:40]: \n"
        all.append(x1)
        let x2 = "[10:40]: \r"
        all+=x2
        let x3 = "[10:40]: \r"
        all+=x3
        let s2 = ""
        let s3 = ""

        let newLine = "\(currentDay),\(all),\(s2),\(s3)\n"

        csvText.append(contentsOf: newLine)

        do {
            try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path!], applicationActivities: [])
            vc.excludedActivityTypes = [
                UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTwitter,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook,
                UIActivity.ActivityType.openInIBooks
            ]

            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } catch {

            print("Failed to create file")
            print("\(error)")
        }

    } else {

        print("## Error")
    }

}
```

**Output:**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEBR6.png)

Does anyone know other solutions to reach a line break in the cell(Like on the image below)?

[image]

Comment: Put the cell value in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

How to create CSV depends on how the CSV reader reads it.

But usual CSV readers accept this sort of escaping:

```
extension String {
    var csvEscaped: String {
        struct My {
            static let specials = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ", \r\n\t\"")
        }
        return self.unicodeScalars.contains{My.specials.contains($0)}
            ? "\"" + self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "\"\"") + "\""
            : self
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let newLine = "\(date.csvEscaped),\(all.csvEscaped),\(s2.csvEscaped),\(s3.csvEscaped)\n"
```